# How do i determine the "sign" of a region of integration in multivariable integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

In 1 dimension if i am given two numbers a<b and function f that is positive for $x \in [a,b]$ i know that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ is positive and $\int_{b}^{a}f(x)dx$ is negative.

However in 2d and above the region of integration is often given simply as a set of numbers: $\iint_{D}f(x)dxdy$

Am i to assume the D in $\iint_{D}f(x)dxdy$ is a "positive region" unless otherwise stated?

Edit: In a technical sense, is the region of integration assumed to be a positively oriented differentiable manifold unless stated otherwise?

Comment: There is no meaningful definition for this idea in higher dimensions, e.g. there is no rule analogous to $\int_a^b f = - \int_b^a f$, at least in principle. (You can argue this as $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n \ge 2$ cannot be "ordered" in the usual way.) Is there a particular context/problem you're working on that makes you ask this question?

Comment: Well it's not really related to any specific problem I'm working on, just wanna make sure I don't make a mistake when changing coordinates.

Comment: But just to clarify: is it convention that $dxdy$ is treated as a "positive unit" of the region of integration? (unless you're working with differential forms that is, which as far as i have understood treats "differential multiplication" as alternative $dx\land dy = - dy /land dx$)

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any "negative regions" in $\mathbb{R}^1$ either. It's just a convention related to the notation $\int_a^bf$, which is defined as $\int_{[a,b]}f$ if $a\leq b$ and $-\int_{[b,a]}f$ if $a\geq b$.

(It probably isn't actually defined that way the first time people learn about integration, but it is still a useful analogy to the multi-dimensional case.)

Answer (score 0):

tl; dr: Don't worry about orientation when calculating integrals over regions.

Caveats: Even in a first multivariable course, *do* take care with orientations of paths in line integrals, and with surface normals when calculating flux across surfaces. And *do* take care with ordinary integrals whose limits are given, signifying an orientation, e.g., if $a < b$ and $f$ is integrable, then
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f = \int_{[a, b]} f = \int_{a}^{b} f(x)\, dx = -\int_{b}^{a} f(x)\, dx.
$$
If someone writes $\displaystyle\int_{b}^{a} f$, it's a good idea to ask their intent.

---

Integrating functions over regions of Euclidean space (or even over Riemannian manifolds, not necessarily oriented or orientable!) amounts to integrating "measures" or "densities"; loosely, absolute values of top-dimensional forms.

Formally, a product of Cartesian differentials "has the same value" regardless of ordering. In the plane, for example, we might write
$$
dx\, dy = dy\, dx = |dx \wedge dy|.
$$
Integrating the constant function $1$ over a box gives the product of the side lengths, while integrating the unit function over a more complicated set gives Jordan or Lebesgue measure.